# why magento latest sample data too large

Tags: installation

i see  sample data of latest version of magento is about 430 mb why so large i gets stucked while downloading can i use older versions sample data

Comment: It is totally possible to answer this question. I see no reason to close it. There are specific reasons why the sample data package is so large, and an answer could also include a link to https://github.com/Vinai/compressed-magento-sample-data/ as a possible source of smaller sample data.

Comment: yeah ,downloading large data of 430 is not easy task for slow connection , i am stuckecd from two days

Comment: For that reason I commented with the link above to a compressed version of the sample data with lower quality versions of the images and the mp3 files. The file sizes vary between 20-66 MB depending on compression type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a *[feel free to edit and insert good reason here]* reason, Magento felt it necessary to include extremely large assets within the sample data package.

There are a number of "lite" versions maintained by the community available,

- https://github.com/sonassi/magento-sample-data/tree/1.9.0.0-lite
- https://github.com/Vinai/compressed-magento-sample-data/

In our version, we merely did the following,

Remove the cache/tmp dirs

```
rm -rf magento-sample-data-1.9.0.0/media/tmp magento-sample-data-1.9.0.0/media/catalog/product/cache
```

Zero byte the MP3 files

```
find magento-sample-data-1.9.0.0 -name '*.mp3' | while read F; do >$F; done
```

Resize the large images to a tenth their size

```
for EXT in jpg png; do
  find magento-sample-data-1.9.0.0 -size +500k -name '*.'$EXT | while read F; do convert $F -resize 10% $F.new; mv $F{.new,} ; done
done
```

Losslessly recompress the image files using MageStack utils

```
/microcloud/scripts_ro/image_optimise.sh magento-sample-data-1.9.0.0
```